# mirror half an image c++

Tags: c++, sfml

so i am trying to mirror an image although only half of it so that my image(a zebra) only has either two butts or two heads, it really doesn't matter which.
i managed to gray scale half the picture with the code i have below.
How should i do to mirror it instead of making it gray?

```
int main()
{
    sf::Image image;
    image.loadFromFile("../Images/zebra.bmp"); 
    sf::Color greyscale(0, 0, 0, 255);
    sf::Color newPixelColor;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y), "Image manipulation");
    sf::Texture imageTexture;
    imageTexture.loadFromImage(image);

    sf::RectangleShape picture;

    picture.setSize(sf::Vector2f((float)image.getSize().x, (float)image.getSize().y));
    picture.setTexture(&imageTexture);

    sf::Event event;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getSize().x; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < image.getSize().y; y++) {
                    if(x > (image.getSize().x) / 2) {
                        int newPixel = image.getPixel(x, y).r;
                        newPixel = image.getPixel(x, y).g;
                        newPixel = image.getPixel(x, y).b;

                        newPixelColor.r = newPixel;
                        newPixelColor.g = newPixel;
                        newPixelColor.b = newPixel;

                        image.setPixel(x, y, newPixelColor);
                    }
                }
            }
            imageTexture.loadFromImage(image);
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(picture);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how should i do to mirror the image instead of just making half of it grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for those who want the answer. Change y with x and x with y and you will get what i was looking for!

```
int halfHeight = image.getSize().y / 2;

for (int y = 0; y < halfHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getSize().x; x++)
    {
        image.setPixel(x, image.getSize().y - 1 - y, image.getPixel(x, y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SFML isn't really made for image manipulation or pixel by pixel calculations (outside shaders). There are far more optmized libraries for that, for example OpenCV.

If you want to draw parts of an image, mirror them, etc. you should just rely on using a `sf::Sprite` or (probably better) a `sf::VertexArray`. You can simply manipulate the texture rectangle or texture coordinates to mirror or adjust the parts you want to display.

For this example I'm using [this public domain image of a Zebra](https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/en/view-image.php?image=16300&picture=zebra).

My example code is pretty self-explanatory so I don't assume it needs a lot of extra explanation:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window({1280, 853}, "Zebra");
    sf::Texture texZebra;
    texZebra.loadFromFile("zebra.jpg");

    sf::VertexArray zebra(sf::Quads);

    // Every vertex is defined by a world coordinate, color, and texture coordinate

    // Define the first quad (left half)
    zebra.append({{0, 0},     sf::Color::White, {0, 0}});
    zebra.append({{640, 0},   sf::Color::White, {640, 0}});
    zebra.append({{640, 853}, sf::Color::White, {640, 853}});
    zebra.append({{0, 853},   sf::Color::White, {0, 853}});

    // Define the right quad (right half)
    zebra.append({{640, 0},     sf::Color::White, {640, 0}});
    zebra.append({{1280, 0},   sf::Color::White, {0, 0}});
    zebra.append({{1280, 853}, sf::Color::White, {0, 853}});
    zebra.append({{640, 853},   sf::Color::White, {640, 853}});

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        sf::RenderStates state;
        state.texture = &texZebra;
        window.draw(zebra, state);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Once running, you'll get a window displaying the left half of the original image, mirrored in the middle:

[image: Example Screenshot]